# Double spider farm - will it work?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In my Minecraft  survival world, I found a spider dungeon *inside* a mineshaft. There is a cave spider spawner close enough that their spawning areas actually overlap by a 2x3x2 area. This means that when I'm within a certain  area, both spawners will be spawning spiders.

I want to make a one-hit kill farm for XP.

Should I try and combine the spawners into one farm, or keep them separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spiders and Cave Spiders are pretty similar. If you want, you can actually combine the two to get more xp. To combine them, it shouldn't be too difficult, just make the waterstreams (or however else you are moving the mobs) to connect together. Just make sure that the cave spiders can't fit out of the killing chamber, otherwise they will poison you! Use a slab with a trapdoor on top to keep them in.

So, my final answer will be that **yes, you should combine the two**. The more mobs, the more xp you will get in the end.